# onMarkerClick() is never called in Emulator

Tags: android

I want to register a OnMarkerClickListener to a GoogleMap:

- implement the GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener interface
- register listener via GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)

but when I click on a marker the callback onMarkerClick() is never called. For test purposes I also implemented OnMapLongClickListener and it works perfectly well.

```
public class ShowCoords extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    LocationListener,
    GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener,
    GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.show_coords);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    if (gpsPermission()) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this);
    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

    if (displayFormat.equals(getString(R.string.heatmapValue))) {
        // display markers as heatmap
    } else if (displayFormat.equals(getString(R.string.clusterValue))) {
        // diplay markers as cluster 
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mMap);
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
        // this causes the problem
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        for (LatLng p : coords) {
            mClusterManager.addItem(new MyClusterItem(p));
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "onMapReady: coords still null, nothing to display");
    }

    //just for testing
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(51.866404, 12.643411)));
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {        
    Log.i(TAG, "onMarkerClick");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onMapLongClick");
}

// removed other callbacks
}
```

Any ideas, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. When I display the markers as a cluster (via [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)) the clustermanager registers as OnMarkerClickListener and the registration of my listener get lost. As a workaround, I omit the clustermanager registration and pass the click event on the clustermanager by myself.